# Rational function field of a curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let C be a smooth plane curve over a field k and k(C) a rational function field of C.

I have already studied on algebraic function fields and of course it mentions transcendence basis. Is k(C) an algebraic function field but is a isomorphic to the rational field of polynomials over K?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the function field is a birational invariant of curves? In particular, $k(C)\cong k(t)$ iff $C$ is birational to the projective line - for example, if $C$ is an elliptic curve, $k(C)\not\cong k(t)$.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks.

Comment: Hello @KReiser. Where can I find this result: $K(C) \simeq k(X) \iff C \simeq \mathbb P^1$?